# 4 Wires in Switch Box - Ceiling Fan/Light

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I wanted to add a remote transmitter to my ceiling fan and the correpsonding wall switch.   When removing the current switch (dual slider fan/light), I have five wires in the switch box. There is a blue wire that powers the light.  A orange wire that powers the fan. There are two black (cloth wires twisted together); one of these is hot and the other is not--and ground.  New switch only has two black and ground.   (Current switch was wired as follows: Black from switch to both cloth blacks.  Red from switch to blue. Yellow from switch to orange.) Confused how to wire new switch with only two blacks and ground.  Thank you!!

[image: wall configuration]
[image: ceiling configuration]

Comment: Have you already fitted the fan with the corresponding remote receiver? Also, what make and model is the new fan switch you're trying to install?

Comment: Not yet.  It is an Eogife3.  But I see it says incandescent only.  So thinking of getting one that handles LED. THX!!!

Comment: Now thinking of going with Lutron Caseta Wireless, so no transmitter needed.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more photos.

Answer (score 1):

The non-live black braided wire is not neutral.  Wires are not neutral simply because a voltage tester doesn't light up.  The non-live black is *onward always-hot*.  It became de-energized because you disconnected it from supply when you separated it. I trust you did not do that hot :)

Take the blue wire out of service. Cap it off at both ends. Tape the cap down (they fall off single wires otherwise).  That's the only time you ever tape a wirenut.

The LINE/SUPPLY black from the new switch joins the 2 cloth switches.

The LOAD/TO-FAN black from the new switch joins the one unattached wire (red).

Up in the fan, connect the fan controller to red and neutral.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Just to confirm, I have an orange wire in box.  Is that what you’re referring to as “red” load/to fan?

Comment: @GPRProductions Yeah sorry, orange. Wow, I'm a conduit guy who owns 11 colors of wire. I shouldn't make a mistake like that lol.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @GPRProductions -- some of the higher-end Caseta stuff requires a neutral wire at the switchbox though

Comment: Although, this is conduit, clearly from the funny wire colors, so a neutral could be pulled.

Comment: Thanks to you both. Much appreciate your time and kindness!

Comment: @GPRProductions -- keep the current setup at the fan; if you need to tie the two hots to the fan together, I'd do it at the switchbox, where it's easier to change if you go to a different fan/light control in the future.

Comment: Wow.  Update. Went back to transmitter.  Caseta was only for a light.   They don’t make Caseta  light/fan combo with a remote.   Eliminated blue on both ends.  Used neutral from transmitter (fixture side) connected to black & onward black from ceiling.   Connected blue from transmitter, light side, to blue from light fixture.  Connected black from transmitter, fan side, to black from fan.   Neutral from transmitter, ceiling side, capped off.  Connected Red from transmitter, ceiling side, to orange load from ceiling.    Success!!!